# Angular 2 provider for a service dependent service that was NOT instantiated by bootstrap()

Tags: angular

Service B holds a reference to Service A - if I were to instantiate Service A via the Angular2 bootstrap() method, all I'd need to do is add a reference to Service A in Service B's constructor and Angular happily injects Service A into Service B... but what if Component 1 needs it's own instance of Service B and Component 2 needs it's own instance of Service B... how can Service B be provided unique instances of its dependent service A (e.g. Component 1's Service A's state should not be affected by Component 2's Service A's state)? --- this means that Service B needs to be able to instantiate independent service A instances... I suppose that I could `new` Service B in Service A (but this isn't dependency injection)... I basically want `providers: []` metadata for services that are injected into services...

or (more simply)

Can someone share a code example of a service that is provided from a somewhere other than the bootstrap() method or a component?

Comment: It sounds very complicated. Can you please provide an example https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way for services to provide their dependencies.

The best you can do is export a providers array and provide that in the desired component.

```
Export class ServiceB {
  constructor(serviceA: ServiceA) {}
 ... 
}

Export const SERVICEB_PROVIDERS = [ ServiceB, ServiceA ];
```

Then in the component:

```
@Component {
  ... 
  providers: [SERVICEB_PROVIDERS]
  ... 
}
```

See this [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5622) in the angular repo for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify a **providers** property in your @Component, you are telling the dependency injection to provide a new instance for this particular component.

If you don't specify the service in your providers, the dependency request bubbles up the next parent component, and will keep looking for providers in each parent component until it finds a provider, or gets to your bootstrap function.

This will give Component1 it's very own ServiceB.  It won't be a reference to the one you provided in your bootstrap:

```
@Component({
    selector: "Component1",
    templateUrl: "./blah/component1.component.html",
    providers: [ServiceB]
})
export class Component1{
...
```

This one will get a ServiceB from your bootstrap function if it doesn't find another providers property in a parent component.

```
@Component({
    selector: "Component2",
    templateUrl: "./blah/component2.component.html"
})
export class Component2{
...
```

Comment: Your response makes sense at the component level - but how can ServiceB get a unique instance of ServiceA (upon which ServiceB is dependent)? (logically) I want something like @Service({providers:[ServiceA]}) @Injectable() export class ServiceB {...}

Comment: This helped me, I wanted one instance of a service shared among many components, and it wasn't working because I was declaring the service in providers on each component, rather than once on the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the follow excerpt from [Victor Savkin's blog post about Angular Dependency Injection](http://victorsavkin.com/post/126514197956/dependency-injection-in-angular-1-and-angular-2)

```
// Angular 2: Configuring LoginService

@Injectable() class LoginService {
  constructor(@Inject("LoginServiceConfig") public config: {url: string}) {}
  //...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<login></login>`,
  directives: [Login],
  providers: [
        LoginService,
        provide("LoginServiceConfig", {useValue: {url: 'myurl'})
    ]
})
class App {}
```

It illustrates how to inject a (child) service into a (parent) service where the (child) service that is injected into the (parent) service is (must be?) provided by the component using the parent where the (parent) service is provided to the component...